# Multiple Homepages for single website according to screen size

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have made font end of website(static website). I want to make multiple home pages for this website according to screen size. for example homepage1.html for mobile screen size and homepage2.html for desktop, and remaining pages(services, contact) would be same for all screen size.

so please help me how to do this without  using php?

in php we can import like this

```
<?php include('homepage1.php') ?>
```

i want to do this same thing using html or js, then i can write function in js like if screen size is less than 700px then import homepage1.html.

If you have any other idea to do this same thing then please guide me..

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design

Comment: Why not use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to scale your website accordingly? No need for multiple homepages

Comment: you could use location.replace in JS when you trigger a function for certain events. That not a very good approach tho in my opinion. Best way to do this is what the other comments say, build it responsive, you can change the complete layout with media queries for different screen sizes

Comment: I have already made it responsive, but i  am new in this field so i am exploring something new  and I got this, and i want to do this same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a simple code. You can add more screen width.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load resize',function(){
        if($(window).width() < 950){
            window.location = "https://www.google.com"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Such as

```
// In index2.php
if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
    window.location = "index1.php";
}

// In index1.php
if (window.innerWidth >= 960) {
    window.location = "index2.php";
}
```

Comment: I have a complete website which contains homepage, about, services, contact but i want to change only homepage and other would be same. so how to import this homepage in main website so that i can change this using  given code.